# Can i use the inverse approximate Pi Function to approximate the nth prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

I'm using an approximation of $x/\ln(x)$ ~ $π(x)$ and I am using the logic that the square root function counts how many squares there are and the log function counts how many powers of base *b* there are, and inverting those functions gives you the nth square or power. The Pi function works the same way as the other listed functions, where the value increases by 1 every new prime, and the same with the approximation, so does it make sense to take the inverse of $f(x)=x/\ln(x)$, which is $f^{-1}(x)=-xW_{-1}(-1/x)$
as the approximation for the nth prime? If so, how good of an approximation is this?

(I used only the branch of $W_{-1}$ which would experience a positive, unbounded growth since using $W_0$ would have given me only values below 2 which I didn't want.)

Comment: That's probably a decent approximation, but I think it's much simpler to just approximate $p_n \sim n \ln n$.

Comment: You can see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number

and

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259997/nth-prime-a-better-approximation

for other ways to approximate the $n$th prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approximation is asymptotically correct. That is $$p_n \sim -n\,W_{-1}(-1/n)$$

but that's not a very good approximation. That's because $\frac{x}{\log x}$ is not a very good approximation of $\pi(x)$ to begin with.

A better approximation of $\pi(x)$ is $\frac{x}{\log x -1}$.

If you invert that you get a much better approximation:

$$p_n \sim -n\,W_{-1}(-e/n)$$

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Yes, Legendre's constant is $1$, that means that the best asymptotic approximation to $\pi(x)$ **of the form** $\frac{x}{\log x - c}$ is when $c=1$. But there are much better approximations which are not of that form.